# Why is there a space in the middle? VBA excel

Tags: string, vba, excel, concatenation

Basic question, getting started at VBA

```
StoreValueLocCol = Left(StoreValueLoc, 1)
StoreValueLocRow = Int(Right(StoreValueLoc, 2) + 1)
StoreValueLoc = StoreValueLocCol & Str(StoreValueLocRow)
MsgBox(StoreValueLoc)
```

I wanted to go down a row in excel VBA, but when i concatenate the strings a space exists between them.

I am using this as a solution but I would like to find out why the space exists

```
StoreValueLoc = Replace(StoreValueLoc, " ", "")
```

Comment: Try vbNewLine or vbCrLf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Str` adds a leading space. Either use `CStr` or just concatenate:

```
StoreValueLoc = StoreValueLocCol & CStr(StoreValueLocRow)
```

or:

```
StoreValueLoc = StoreValueLocCol & StoreValueLocRow
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps to let folks know data types and such so that we can get a good idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

I'm assuming that `StoreValueLoc`is a Range variable.  If you're looking to separate the columns and rows you could just use `.` notation to utilize built in VBA functions.  See below:

```
storeValueLocRow = storeValueLoc.Row
storeValueLocCol = storeValueLoc.Column
MsgBox(storeValueLocRow & ", " & storeValueLocCol)
```

**Note: If the range is not a single cell Column and row functions will return the first column and first row in the range**